# Accessing Subversion repository with 2 hops using svn+ssh protocol

Tags: svn, ssh

My Ubuntu Subversion server is not directly accessible to the Internet, 192.168.1.2

My public Ubuntu machine is exposed through the DMZ at 192.168.1.1

I've setup port forwarding from 192.168.1.1:3906 to 192.168.1.2:3906, but I have no idea how this would work with svn+ssh since one extra hop is required to reach my Subversion server

**edit:** For anybody going through the same problem, my confusion came because I was trying to port forward to my SVN server (running a daemon at port '3906') but **accessing your SVN server through SSH is totally different from accessing your SVN server running a daemon (at 3906)**. You need to treat this as a typical ssh connection. Both of the methods below worked once I edited my settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put something like this in your .ssh/config file:

```
Host subversionserver
        Host=192.168.1.1
        ProxyCommand = ssh 192.168.1.1 /usr/local/bin/nc -w 60 192.168.1.2 %p
        ForwardX11 = no
        User = myusername
        ForwardAgent = yes
```

Then you'll be able to connect to your ssh server with just:

```
ssh subversionserver
```

Basically you'll log in to your public box and run the netcat command once you get in.  Your desired to the subversion server SSH connection will be going over the netcat connection.

Obviously you'll need to have netcat somewhere on your box.

The version in my .ssh/config file has a wildcard Host and uses %h in the netcat command.  Very useful when you want to proxy through for all the boxes in a production environment that you have to go through a DMZ to get to.

Comment: Small typo: ".12" should be ".2"

Comment: I assume this goes into the .sssh/config of the outside machine trying to get in. If so, when u run "ssh subverionserver" how does it know the location? (i dont see anything about loc or ip address in your host config)

Comment: I used the IP addresses you provided for your machines (in this case 192.168.1.1).  You can replace them with actual hostnames.  The outside machine would need to know the external hostname, the public facing box would need to know the subversion servers ip address.

Answer (score 3):

Is your sshd listening on port 3906 (rather than the standard port 22)? If so you should be able to connect with e.g.

```
   $ svn co svn+ssh://MYHOST:3906/svn/trunk/whatever
```

If not, forward port 3906 on .1 to 22 on .2.

Or forward port 22 on .1 to 22 on .2 if you don't need to ssh anywhere else on your intranet.

Comment: If i understand port forwarding correctly, I access my public PC from work through ssh port 22 so i am not sure i can forward it to .2

maybe if i add 3906 to my sshd listening ports then that would be forwarded?

Is